# Finding Possible Options For Validators For Zend_Filter_Input

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is an example of setting up the validators as explained in the Manual http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html

```
$validators = array('account' => 'Alpha');
```

This checks that the input field is on Alphabets.

The question is, how do i find out the other options that can be used for Validating apart from "Alpha"

Where can I find the other Validation constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you are looking at is the manual page for Zend_Filter, you'd be better reading the [Zend_Validate](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html) page.

If you look at [this manual page](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html), you will see a list of standard validator classes. You can use any of these as an option in `$validators`. You just use the name of the validator as the option.

For example to use the [Date](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.date) validator you would do this:-

```
$validators = array('account' => 'Date');
```

You can also find a list of validators if you look in your `library/Zend/Validate` folder.